# How to sync pair of radio buttons in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to sync two or more pair of radio buttons in Angular4. 
I want both to sync default input buttons and Angular Material radio buttons.

These are input radio button

```
<table style="width:100%">
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="Breakfast">
    <input type="radio" name="Breakfast">
</td>

<td>
    <input type="radio" name="Lunch" >
    <input type="radio" name="Lunch" >
</td>
</table>
```

And These are Angular Material Radio

```
<md-radio-group>
  <md-radio-button value="1">Option 1</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="2">Option 2</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
<md-radio-group>
  <md-radio-button value="3">Option 3</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button value="4">Option 4</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

For Example:- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BUbHf/1/)

Comment: you can use ngModel for same.

Comment: @AmanJain I already tried that, ngModel won't work, can you please share one example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `(change)` event from Angular to bind a method when the value is changed. I used this on the inputs to know when any of them changed value : `(change)="onChange1($event.target.value)"`

Here is a plunkr showing the result : https://plnkr.co/edit/20igbMdRaY5QE6RtSr1a?p=preview

You can then bind properties with `NgModel` to bind the two of them together.